# What is the post-for/if syntax called?

Tags: perl, nomenclature

Does the following syntax have a name?

```
print for ( @ARGV );

exit if $x;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're [statement modifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers).

Answer (score 4):

It's called "Statement Modifiers" in the [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes they are known as [postfix](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl%3a%3aCritic%3a%3aPolicy%3a%3aControlStructures%3a%3aProhibitPostfixControls) constructions.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the the components of the snippet, yes, those are statement modifiers.

If you mean the construct of the statement I would say following:

**pre-condition/prefix construct:**

... the condition (if $x) is written before (pre) the statement ( { ... exit ...;})

*It's the normal (most used) way to write those statements.*

```
for ( @ARGV ){
    print;
}

if ($x) {
    exit;
}
```

**post-condition/postfix construct:**

... the condition (if $x) is written after (post) the statement ( { ... exit ...;})

*It's the other way around. Mostly for shortcuts, or one-liners. 
Some find it usefull, but it's generally discouraged because or readability and understanding: see [@mob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5722998/4940240)*
*Or from PerlMonks: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=177971*

```
print for ( @ARGV );

exit if $x;
```